# How to increase maxPostSize in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm getting the following error when uploading a large file:
*The multi-part request contained parameter data (excluding uploaded files) that exceeded the limit for maxPostSize set on the associated connector]*

I have the following in application.properties (I've also tried setting these to -1 i.e. unlimited)

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=250MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=250MB
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size=250000000
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=250000000
```

And the following in the main application class, Application.java:

```
/* Configures the embedded Tomcat max post size */
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> containerCustomizer() {

    return (TomcatServletWebServerFactory container) -> {

        String propVal = environment.getProperty("spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size");
        int postSize = 10000000; // Default - 10MB

        if (!propVal.isEmpty()) {
            postSize = Integer.parseInt(propVal.substring(0, propVal.length() - 2));

            if (propVal.endsWith("KB")) {
                postSize = postSize * 1000;
            }
            else if (propVal.endsWith("MB")) {
                postSize = postSize * 1000000;
            }
        }
        // Needs to be final for lambda expression bellow
        final int maxPostSize = postSize;

        container.addConnectorCustomizers((connector) -> connector.setMaxPostSize(maxPostSize));
    };
}
```

However, I'm still getting the error. Does anyone perhaps have any suggestions or ideas please?

Spring Boot Version = 2.6.6, Tomcat Version = Apache Tomcat/9.0.62

Comment: Your customizer actually disables the use of the properties.

Comment: The server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size and server.tomcat.max-swallow-size properties were set in application.properties with the hope of resolving this error so it wasn't part of the initial implementation i.e. the maxPostSize on the Tomcat connector was supposed to be set with the setMaxPostSize call but this doesn't seem to be working which is why I tried using the properties which also doesn't seem to be working. Are you suggesting I remove the customizer and just use properties?

Comment: Are you using the embedded tomcat or are you deploying your application to a tomcat server?

Comment: I am deploying the application to a tomcat server.

Comment: Then that won't work as that is for the embedded container. You will need to configure the tomcat instance you are deploying to. The `server.*` properties don't apply nor do the `TomcatCustomizer` run/apply as it isn't an embedded tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

simple, in `application.properties`

```java
# What you want
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=20MB
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow, as mentioned these properties are set. As a side note - if I'm not mistaken setting spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size and spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size actually resolves this error: the request was rejected because its size (11716468) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)], and not this error: The multi-part request contained parameter data (excluding uploaded files) that exceeded the limit for maxPostSize set on the associated connector].